# displaying a body background image using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have to display a background image of a jsp page using jquery. The name of the image  file is available in static member of a Java class. I tried like, created a static member in a Java class (ImageClass)

```
         public static final String img_file="welcome.png"
```

and in jsp file, I imported this java class and inside script tag

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
          $('body').css('background-image','url(/resource/'<%=ImageClass.img_file%>')');
         });
```

But the image is not getting displayed and I am sure the image is available in the mentioned path. Am I doing anything wrong ? Is this the rite way to do ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your image has minimum fs permission (644) to be seen? is your body tall enough to show the image?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS that get's outputted? run firebug for example and see if there are any javascript or CSS errors. Also open the NET tab in firebug to try to catch any random access to an unexistant image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote

```
... ,'url(/resource/'<%=ImageClass.img_file%>')'
```

try instead

```
... ,'url(/resource/<%=ImageClass.img_file%>)'
```

without quotes around the server side echo, otherwise you may have a js parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript ready function does not seem to be complete. add ");" at the end of your code and try.